# Multiple shipping addresses

Tags: commerce

We're building a Drupal 7 website with Drupal Commerce and our client would like to give the customer the ability to add multiple shipping addresses on the registration page.

The customer would then be given the option to select one of these addresses during checkout.

Is this native functionality or can we deliver this via a module?

Answer (score 0):

Lucky you, someone built exactly that:

[Commerce Addressbook Extra](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_addressbook_extra)

> This module for Drupal Commerce extends Commerce Addressbook module and allows to add customer profiles from Register form.

It sits on top of [Commerce Addressbook](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_addressbook)

> Commerce Addressbook is a module that allows authenticated customers to reuse
>   previously entered addresses during checkout.
>   They can manage all entered addresses in their user panel (user/%user/addressbook).